# check if values in a series of columns are within a certain number of values from those in another series of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| col1 | col2   | col3  | col4  | col5  | col6   | col7   |
|______|________|_______|_______|_______|________|________|
| x    | 2003   | 2004  | 2009  | 2002  | 2011   | NA     |
|------|--------|-------|-------|-------|--------|--------|
| y    | 2004   |  NA   | NA    | 2002  | 2004   | NA     |
|------|--------|-------|-------|-------|--------|--------|
| x    | 2007   |  2009 | NA    | 2010  | 2012   | 2013   |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to check how many times per category in col1, the values in col5:col7 occur within 2 or less years after (0-2) any of the values in col2:col4.

so the desired result would be something like:

```
[[x]] 
2
[[y]]
1
```

or as a dataframe like this:

```
col1 | count |
______________
x    | 2
--------------
y    | 1
```

I think there has to be a dplyr way to do this? 
like something with `gather()` and `filter()`? 
or some approach using `sapply` to get the difference between the values and then just counting the number > 2?

The main issue I'm having is how the syntax when not all of the column have values for each row, and I want to compare the values in col2:col4 to all of the values in col5:col7, not just to a specific column.

Comment: Maybe `gather`, `group_by` col1 and count?

Comment: no, should be in range 0-2 years from col2:col4. just editted to try to make that clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Thanks @NelsonGon this works, but I think there is probably a simpler approach:

```
#convert to long format
test <- mydf %>%
  gather( first_group, year.1, col2:col4) %>%
  gather(scond_group, year.2, col5:col7) 

#remove the NA values
test <- test[-c(which(is.na(test$year.2))),]
test <- test[-c(which(is.na(test$year.1))),]

#count number fitting criteria
test2 <- test %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  filter(year.2 >= year.1 & year.2 <= year.1 + 2) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) 

##result
#test1
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#depend_var     n
#<chr>      <int>
#1 x         2
#2 y         1
```